# WPF button with custom template can only be pressed on content

Tags: .net, wpf, button

I've got a button style + template as follows:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="RepeatButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="RepeatButton">
                <Border Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlColor}}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">            
                    <Path Data="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <Path.Fill>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="PathBrush" Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkColor}" />
                        </Path.Fill>
                    </Path>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The button is used like this:

```
<RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Content="M 0 4 L 8 4 L 4 0 Z" />
```

However, the button can only be pressed when the mouse is over the path, not over the whole button. How do I get the button to be pressed when the mouse is over the button but not over the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Background property of the `Border` element in your `ControlTemplate` is set incorrectly. It expects `Brush` and you provided `Color`. Since  it's DynamicResource the brush is not set at all. So it's not visible for Click. Simply provide Brush.

This should do the trick :)

```
<Border Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
```